# Center text underneath images in a row

Tags: html, css

The text representing each image is currently located to the right of the image. I want the text to be centered underneath its corresponding image, how do I achieve this?

Please note that I applied `display: inline-bock` on the list items, so they are in a row.

```css
#footer1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 10px solid #e3e3e3;
}
#footer1>ul>li {
  padding: 0 8px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#footer1 a:hover img {
  border: 1px solid #5cadff;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px 2px #5cadff;
}
#footer1 img {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin-left: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer1">
  <h2> SOURCES </h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.wikipedea.com" title="wikipedia">
        <img height="50" src="http://www.placehold.it/50" width="50">
      </a>
      w
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.google.com" title="google">
        <img height="50" src="http://www.placehold.it/50" width="50">
      </a>
      Google
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com" title="youtube">
        <img height="50" src="http://www.placehold.it/50" width="50">
      </a>
      Youtube
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.nlm.nih.gov/" title="Nih.gov">
        <img height="50" src="http://www.placehold.it/50" width="50">
      </a>
      Nih
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.medindia.net" title="MedIndia.net">
        <img height="50" src="http://www.placehold.it/50" width="50">
      </a>
      MedIndia
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Caan you please add the css also

Comment: @RinoRaj I added it pls check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this without any changes to your existing HTML by doing this:

```
li{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  width:70px;
}

li img{
  margin:0 10px;
}
```

The text-align centers all text and child elements inside the li. The width needs to be large enough that no caption will be too large to fit in that width. (If a caption won't fit in the allotted width, then the centering is wrecked.)

I added the left and right margin to the image for a little bit of future-proofing in case you later want to include a very short caption in your list. With that margin, even a very short caption will be forced to the next line (instead of next to the image) since 50 px image width + 10 margin on each side leaves no room for text.

Answer (score 2):

Edited for float, keeps these inline and overflows if doesn't fit on page.

```html
<style>
  .container {
    clear: both;
  }
  ul li {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center
  }
  ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a title="wikipedia" href="https://www.wikipedea.com">
        <img src="wikipedia.png" height="50" width="50">wikipedia
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a title="wikipedia" href="https://www.wikipedea.com">
        <img src="wikipedia.png" height="50" width="50">wikipedia
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a title="wikipedia" href="https://www.wikipedea.com">
        <img src="wikipedia.png" height="50" width="50">wikipedia
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using div?

Comment: I checked it but it donot make any change

Comment: Updated to not have the div inside

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this**

HTML:

```
 <div id="footer1">
        <h2> SOURCES </h2>
        <div class="item">
            <a title="wikipedia" href="https://www.wikipedea.com">
                <img src=""/>
            </a>
            <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a title="wikipedia" href="https://www.wikipedea.com">
                <img src=""/>
            </a>
            <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a title="wikipedia" href="https://www.wikipedea.com">
                <img src=""/>
            </a>
            <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.item {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
}
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.caption {
    display: block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/ejhosxs1/3/)

Comment: but they are not inline

Comment: Can you make it clear? What did you meant by inline?

Comment: I applied inline-block property over them so they lie in a line. pls check my EDIT in question. I want these images to lie in a row and then text right under it